# How to make the discord bot react to the user's command message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@commands.command(name='clear', aliases=['clean', 'cleanup'])
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(self, ctx, message, limit: int = 10) -> None:
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(":white_check_mark:")
        messages = await ctx.channel.purge(bulk=True, limit=limit)
        embed=discord.Embed(title=f"`{len(messages)}` mensagens deletadas com sucesso", color=COR_PRINCIPAL)
        embed.set_author(name="Plugin de comandos do Tatrantolo",icon_url=ICONE)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=5)
```

I'd like the bot to add a reaction to the user's message, but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your bot have permission to add reactions?

Comment: Yes, It does have permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using *standart* discord emojis, you must react with the unicode of the character, to get it simply `\{emoji}`, send it and copy the emoji. In your case the unicode of the emoji is ✅.

```py
await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
```

EDIT:

```py
@commands.command()
async def testing(self, ctx):
    await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
```

Comment: I changed it, but still doesn't worl. I received the following error: ctx is a required argument that is missing.

Comment: The error is not cause of that line, you've must deleted something.

Comment: Yeah, I think this too, but I can discover what's wrong

Comment: You probably deleted something, can't help with that

Comment: I think I solved the error, I shouldn't had to use "message" in `async def clear(self, ctx, limit: int = 10) -> None:`

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helped